# ASP.NET aspx button click reset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 Asp button in a page (buttonUsername and buttonReset). First one perform an AD search, and set a private variable, while second button perform an action, using variable previously set.

```
public partial class ResetPassword : System.Web.UI.Page {
    private UserPrincipal tmpPwdUser;

    protected void buttonUsername_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.tmpPwdUser = ...
    }

    protected void buttonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        myObj.myFunction(this.tmpPwdUser); // --> this.tmpPwdUser is void
    }
}
```

My problem: `this.tmpPwdUser` is correctly set in `buttonUsername_Click` function, but when `buttonReset_Click` event is triggered, variable `this.tmpPwdUser` is `null`. I guess that when event is triggered, page is reloaded, so each local variable is reset. Is there a way to preserve state when button si clicked?

Comment: why not just put that value in a session variable or view states

Comment: @Rex finally i used states

Answer (score 2):

As you suspect, a new instance of the form is created for the new request. You have to preserve the value of the variable between those requests. One way to do this is to store the value in [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx).

You can create a helper property that stores and retrieves the value from ViewState:

```
private UserPrincipal TmpPwdUser
{
  get
  {
    return ViewState["UniqueViewStateKey"] As UserPrincipal;
  }
  set
  {
    ViewState["UniqueViewStateKey"] = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the OnEvent property instead of the onclick

Poperty on button ( OnCommand="Submit_Command")
in code behind
Submit_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
}